# WordPress - Custom Query with List of Times, 1:00am is before 2:00pm - How to Order Correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom query in WordPress that is pulling a time assigned to a post item in a custom meta field.  The times are entered in the following format:

*1:00am, 2:00am, 1:00pm, 2:00pm, 3:00pm, etc*

The query displays the posts in order of this time, however, its displaying them out of order, like this:

*1:00am, 1:00pm, 2:00am, 2:00pm, 3:00am, 3:00pm, etc.*

I need it to display them in the proper order, like this: *1:00am, 2:00am, 3:00am....11:00am, 12:00pm, 1:00pm, 2:00pm, 3:00pm, etc*

I thought about simply switching to a 24 hour clock, but some users are not familiar with it.

Here is my query, can someone help me with a solution:

```
<ul>
<?php
$args=array(
  'taxonomy' => 'day',
  'term' => 'monday',
  'post_type' => 'schedule',
  'meta_key' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'orderby' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'order' => 'asc',  
  'posts_per_page' => 24,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php $show_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tr_show_name', true ); ?>
      <?php $show_time = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tr_show_time', true ); ?>
      <li>
        <?php echo $show_time;?> - <?php echo $show_name;?>
      </li>
      <?php endwhile; } wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could switch it to the 24 hour clock and then format it appropriately when displayed. Since WP's meta values are strings, you're not going to be able to get it to sort properly with 12-hour times without using a custom query.

Comment: jprofitt is correct. Entering the Meta Values using a 24 hours clock and then formatting the information on the front-end would be your best bet without resorting to a messy SQL call.

Comment: How would I format it on the front end? Alot of my users have complained when using a 24 hour clock in the past, which is why I switched to a 12 hour one.  Is it possible to format it back to 12 hour?  Would I use a jQuery find/replace or somethign else?

Comment: Just use PHP functions to format it appropriately in your template

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery to solve this as, personally, I found it easier to do than in PHP.

I used this script and the following code:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/

```
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /00:00/gi, "12:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /01:00/gi, "1:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /02:00/gi, "2:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /03:00/gi, "3:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /04:00/gi, "4:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /05:00/gi, "5:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /06:00/gi, "6:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /07:00/gi, "7:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /08:00/gi, "8:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /09:00/gi, "9:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /10:00/gi, "10:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /11:00/gi, "11:00am" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /12:00/gi, "12:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /13:00/gi, "1:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /14:00/gi, "2:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /15:00/gi, "3:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /16:00/gi, "4:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /17:00/gi, "5:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /18:00/gi, "6:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /19:00/gi, "7:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /20:00/gi, "8:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /21:00/gi, "9:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /22:00/gi, "10:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /23:00/gi, "11:00pm" );
$("#whats-on-container *").replaceText( /24:00/gi, "12:00am" );
```

Comment: Even if you don't mind using JavaScript neither elegant nor performant.

Answer (score 0):

As jprofit said in the comments section, use the 24 hour clock for your meta values. Then, to format to a 12-hour string, here's what you need to do:

```
<?php
function twentyfourToTwelve($time)
{
    return date('g:i:sa', strtotime($time));
}
?>
```

and where you need to show the time,

```
<?=twentyfourToTwelve($postTime)?>
```